# Twitter Typeahead - How I can use "afterSelect" to jump to annother section of the website?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

I tried to jump after selection with "window.location.hash = '#section3';", but it doesn't work this way..

```
$('#inputField').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
            return $.get('test.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return process(data);
            });
        },
        afterSelect: function (item) {
            window.location.hash = '#section3';
        }
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: section3 is an element in the same page?

Comment: Yes it is on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the window.location to scrollTop

**SCRIPT**

```
$('#inputField').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get('test.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            return process(data);
        });
    },
    afterSelect: function (item) {
        //window.location.hash = '#section3';
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#section3').offset().top }, 1000);
    }
});
```